# How to get unread message count for group messages?

Tags: javascript, mesibo

I have implemented Mesibo on premises successfully,
Now I have to display unread message count in navigation.

I can get unread message count for direct chat but I cannot find unread message count for group message.

If there are three members in group,
how to indicate that message is read by specific members.